# I am getting this kind of error whenever i running this code

Tags: python-3.x

My Code:-
`one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])`

The Error shown:
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'`

Comment: Please read the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html categorical_features is not an argument to this function.

Answer (score 0):

`OneHotEncoder` doesn't have a parameter name `categorical_features`.

> After defining the `one_hot_encoder=OneHotEncoder()` object, use the `fit_transform()` method to encode the categorical data.

[Visit this for more..](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)